# WebView Local CSS

Tags: objective-c, css, cocoa, webkit

How can I load a webpage, eg. google.com and then **load a local CSS file that overrides certain styles?**

The first part I can do, it is the latter that I seem to be unable to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, the answer turned out to be quite simple.

```
WebPreferences *webPrefs = [WebPreferences standardPreferences];
[webPrefs setUserStyleSheetEnabled:YES];
//Point to wherever your local/custom css is
[webPrefs setUserStyleSheetLocation:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"style" withExtension:@"css"]];

//Set your webview's preferences
[myWebView setPreferences:webPrefs];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same here except in my case I want to load it from a specific directory from my OS X Directory.

```objective-c
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
WebPreferences *webPrefs = [WebPreferences standardPreferences];
[webPrefs setUserStyleSheetEnabled:YES];
NSString *folder = @"~/Library/Application Support/irccloud/Style/";
folder = [folder stringByExpandingTildeInPath];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:folder] == NO) {
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:folder withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL];
}
//Point to wherever your local/custom css is
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/ali/Library/Application Support/irccloud/Style/style.css"];
[webPrefs setUserStyleSheetLocation:fileURL];
//Set your webview's preferences
[webView setPreferences:webPrefs];
```

Comment: Are you showing your own example or asking a question? My question here is already answered, as I found the solution. If you're asking a question, I'd suggest you post a new one rather than commenting on a solved, 2-year-old Q/A.

Comment: I just saw your question really useful then I modify it to make it work with a different path that you can specify which is an alternative way of doing it and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift:

```
    // Now kick start css
    let ourWebPrefs:WebPreferences = WebPreferences.standardPreferences();
    ourWebPrefs.userStyleSheetEnabled = true;
    ourWebPrefs.userStyleSheetLocation = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("webview", withExtension: "css");
    customWebView.preferences = ourWebPrefs;
```